# cleaner way to echo all elements of an array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Ive got an associative array like this

```
$array = array (
    "name" => "bob",
    "age" => "22",
    "sex" => "male"
)
```

and to return this data to the screen im using

```
echo $array['name'] . $array['age'] . $array['sex'];
```

is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: [`r($array)`](https://github.com/digitalnature/php-ref) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better reading use the following function:

```
function print_array($input) {
  return '<pre>'.$print_r($input, true).'</pre>';
}
```

for working with it use:

```
echo print_array($array);
```

This prints out a pre formatted array, where you dont have to look in the source to view it propperly

Comment: this is what im using, its serving well

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this if you just don't want to print elements of array  and do some other stuff.

```
foreach($array as $item){
    echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for debugging you could use

```
print_r($array);
```

or

```
var_dump($array);
```

Also you could look at [vsprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) which would allow you to format a string with all of the elements of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$array = array (
    "name" => "bob",
    "age" => "22",
    "sex" => "male"
);

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value . ' - ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$array = array (
"name" => "bob",
"age" => "22",
"sex" => "male"
);
function print_array($arr){
    $keys=  array_keys($arr);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        echo $arr[$key].' ';
    }
}
print_array($array);
```